# Sort sequences of the form ABCABCABC, ABABAB, ABCDABCD, etc.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, sorting

You are given a sequence of distinct elements $P$ and a positive integer $R$. Consider the sequence obtained by repeating $P$ $R$ times and concatenating together. For example, if $P = \langle A, B\rangle$ and $R = 3$, then the resulting sequence $P^R$ is $\langle A, B, A, B, A, B \rangle$.

We would like to transform this sequence into another sequence such that identical elements are now adjacent to each other (more formally, for a sequence $S$, we would like to find a permutation $S'$ of $S$ such that for any two $S'_i$ and $S'_j$ such that $S'_i = S'_j$, for any integer $i \le k \le j$ we must have $S'_i = S'_k = S'_j$). The only operation we can perform on this sequence is swapping two elements.

For example, with $P = \langle A, B \rangle$, let $S = P^3 = \langle A, B, A, B, A, B \rangle$. Consider $S' = \langle A, A, A, B, B, B \rangle$. We can transform $S$ to $S'$ by swapping $S_2$ and $S_5$, thus, we can obtain $S'$ from $S$ by using a single swap. We can also consider $S' = \langle B, B, B, A, A, A \rangle$, in which case we need two swaps.

Is there an algorithm to do this? How should this be done if we want the minimum number of swaps?

Comment: Any sort algorithm works fine.  You just need to specify your comparison function to put them in the order you want.

Comment: @RossMillikan The problem is that there is no way of telling which value is bigger, because they can be anything. The sequence could be "cold, hot, cold, hot". So I was thinking of some kind of permutations two by two given P and R, but I can't figure out how to achieve the minumum number of steps.

Comment: If you can't tell which is bigger, how can you define the sort you want?  You can certainly scan each sequence and count P's and R's and append that data to each sequence. You have not defined what you want to come first-that is the comparison function.

Comment: Can we assume that the patterns consist of distinct characters? If so, I think I should be able to come up with a provably optimal solution.

Comment: @Irvan I'm not sure about what you meant. Could you be more specific? Maybe un example...

Comment: @carla So, an element is basically a pattern repeated R times right? (for example, the first is the pattern ABC repeated 3 times). Can we assume that original pattern (e.g., ABC here) consist of distinct characters (that is, ABCA repeated 3 times forming ABCAABCAABCA is not allowed for example)

Comment: @Irvan Yes, Irvan, that's the case, they never repeat.

Comment: @carla Hm I'm only able to come up with an algorithm that minimize the number of elements that must be moved, not the number of swaps (in particular, if the number of displaced elements is $D$, then the number of swaps range between $\lfloor D / 2\rfloor$, $D-1$).

Comment: @Irvan I was specting the minumum number of swaps, altough your algorithm might also be interesting to share. ( Regarding your edits, I'm doubtful about accepting them, because 1st, it's become more formal but more complicated to understand, and 2nd, it's gonna look like Antoine answer was nonsense)

Comment: I had difficulty understanding the initial problem statement, and I thought this would prevent interested people from actually trying to solve this. Also, you can always edit your own posts.

For the version where you want to minimize the number of displaced elements, it can be solved greedily. I can share this as an answer if you want (but perhaps a bit later).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17706/discussion-between-carla-and-irvan).

Comment: @Irvan OK. If you have the time, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: This solution is provably optimal with the assumption that the function we want to minimize is the number of elements that have to be swapped. I think this should also be optimal for the other case, but I do not give such proof.

We denote by "displaced element" the elements of $S$ that is different than the element of $S'$ in the same location (that is, the element that need to be swapped). If $R$ divides $|P|$, then we can use any possible $S'$ and we will have the same number of displaced elements. Thus, we consider the case where $R \not = P$.

We will first consider the case where $|P|$ and $R$ are coprime to each other. $S'$ consists of $|P|$ group of $R$ consecutive characters, one for each element of $P$. Let the element of the $i$-th group of consececutive characters in $S'$ be noted by $G_{S'}(i)$ (for example, if $S' = \langle A, A, B, B \rangle$, then $G_{S'}(1) = A$ and $G_{S'}(2) = B$).

Now, consider $S'$ obtained by setting $G_{S'}(i)$ to the $(((i-1)R \mod |P|) + 1)$-th character in $P$. Since $|P|$ and $R$ are coprime to each other, $1 \le R \mod |P| < |P|$, and thus all the elements of $G_{S'}$ are unique. In particular, each character in $P$ appears exactly once. Thus, $S'$ is a valid transformed sequence.

Now we claim that this $S'$ consist of a minimum number of displaced elements. We show this by showing that for each group in $S'$, there exists exactly $\lceil R / |P| \rceil$ elements that are not displaced (note that this is the maximum possible such elements for each group, thus this is optimal). The index of the first character of the $i$-th group is $(i-1) R + 1$. However, the $(i \cdot R + 1)$-th character of $P^R$ is exactly equal to $G_{S'}(i)$ and thus the claim holds.

Now suppose $R$ and $|P|$ are not coprime to each other. Let $x = \gcd(R, |P|)$ and $y = \text{lcm}(R, |P|)$. We now set $G_{S'}(i)$ to the $(x((i-1)(R/x) \mod (|P|/x)) + \lfloor (i-1) / y \rfloor + 1)$-th character of $P$. This is also optimal and have the same guarantees as the case where $R$ and $|P|$ are coprime.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your sequence is given as array $A$ and $A[i]$, $1\leq i\leq PR$, $i$-th symbol in $A$.

If you want to sort $A$, then elements of $A$ have to be comparable, i. e. given two elements $x$ and $y$ of $A$, you have to be able to determine whether $x$ is greater than $y$, $y$ is greater than $x$, or $x$ equals $y$.

Given only a sequence **hot**, **cold**, **hot**, **cold** we can argue which of cases
**hot** $<$ **cold**, **hot** $>$ **cold**, **hot** $=$ **cold** holds. Skier would go for the first, swimmer for the second and a stone (which doesn't care of temperatures) would go for the third case, hence the algorithm itself cannot *know* how to compare these elements.

If you know, how to compare the elements of $A$, proceed as follows:

1. Sort the subsequence $A[1]$, $\dots$, $A[P]$ and save the result into array $B$
2. Define array $C$ of length $PR$.
3. `for j = 0, 1, ... , R - 1 repeat:
       for i = 1, 2, ... P repeat:
           C[P * j + i] = B[i]`
4. Return $C$

This is algorithm with running time $\mathcal{O}(PR\log P)$, which is faster than sorting the whole given array $A$ (which would take $\mathcal{O}(PR\log (PR))$ time).

Comment: I liked your detailed answer. As I said, the 1st step is not necessary, the subsequent steps do solve the problem. However, I might confess I'd like to know if there is a optimum permutation algorithm to do the job. I'm gonna edit my question to see if someone has something to add, otherwise, I'll accept your answer.